# MySQL - Insert fields if id is present in another table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I  have two tables, one called `product_text` with a products name, description and category. The other called `product_price` with the products `selling_price` and `cost_price`.

I want to update the `product_price` table with generic values, for example, the `cost_price` as `0.01` and the `selling_price` as `0.01`

I need to somehow insert this information into the `product_price` table for each row that exists in the `product_text` table.

For example, if I have:

```
id name     description category
1  example  example     hats
2  example2 example2    socks
```

in the `product_text` table, I want to insert:

```
id selling_price cost_price
1  0.01          0.01
2  0.01          0.01
```

into the `product_price` table.

I want to do this for a million items, so need an efficient way of doing it.

Please help

Comment: Do you want to insert into product_price or update it?  This makes a difference in how you might approach this.

Comment: Hi Mike, update would be nice. I can empty the table and do an insert, but if theres a way of me not having to empty the table first, that would be nice! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
insert into product_price (id, selling_price, cost_price)
select id, 0.01, 0.01 from product_text
```

Comment: Magento reindexing prices = 2 hours

Comment: juergen d's Solution = 0.1 seconds

Answer (score 0):

You can just update across a join like this:

```
UPDATE product_price AS pp
INNER JOIN product_text AS pt ON pp.id = pt.id
SET pp.cost_price = 0.01, pp.selling_price = 0.01
```

One note, looking at your table schema, it doesn't seem to make sense that these aren't just a single table.